# How to separate functional logic and user interface when getting data

Tags: reactjs, axios

In the application, I get data on the user by clicking on the button. I use Axios for this. Now the problem is that I need to move the logic of getting data into a separate file. How can i do this? In the App component I use createContext and pass the user change function to the button and in the other component I need to display the username when clicked. I can't figure out how to properly separate the logic for getting data into a separate service.js file

```js
//App.js
export const AppContext = createContext();

function App() {
  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState();
  const value = { userInfo, setUserInfo };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <AppContext.Provider value={value}>
        <User/>
      </AppContext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
}

//NextButton.js

const NextButton = () => {
  const handleUser = () => {
    getUser();
  };
  return <button onClick={handleCharacter}>NEXT</button>;
};

//User.js
const User = () => {
const { userInfo } = useContext(AppContext);
  return (
    <>
      <NextButton />
        <p className="user-name">{characterInfo}</p>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

```js
//services.js

export default function getUser() {
  axios.get("https://api/user/1/").then((res) => {
    console.log(res.data.name);
  });
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what is the issue, where comes `characterInfo` (in `User.js`) from?

Comment: Is there a reason why the state for `userInfo` is on that top level? I would argue strongly against the use of `useContext` in this instance too

Comment: The question is that I don't know how to write services.js correctly so that this file is responsible for the logic for receiving data. But I need to use context there to change userInfo on click

Comment: If you want to separate your data from your **UI,** then you need to try Redux toolkit. Ya I know that need to work hard but end of the day you will diffidently satisfy.